# Variable Not Being Written to File

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get all the images, their names and sizes from a folder. I there are over 2000 of them. I know enough about programming that I was able to piece together this code from other stack overflow questions. Everything works as expected except the line `$imgInfo | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append`.

```
$outFile = "G:\tempFile\imageSizes.txt"

$(Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg).FullName | ForEach-Object { 
    $img = [Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_); 
    $imgInfo = "$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_))  $($img.Width)  x  $($img.Height)"
    return $imgInfo   # this line is to check that $imgInfo has the correct information
    $imgInfo | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append   # this line isn't working
}
```

I tried replacing `$imgInfo | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append` with `$imgInfo | Add-Content -Path $outFile` and creating the appropriate file, but that didn't work either.

Comment: What do you think `return` is doing?

Comment: `return` terminates the `ForEach-Object` scriptblock (code in between `{ }`).

Comment: I should have thought of that. What is the best way to print a value contained in a variable in PowerShell? Is there a `print` function similar to `cout` in c++ or do I just write `$imgInfo` to have the value stored in the variable printed to the screen?

Comment: Usually, if you want to display something on the console, you'd use `Write-Host`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only wish to check it then don't use *return* ; it gets out of the block.

just replace

```
 return $imgInfo
```

with

```
Write-output $imgInfo
```